# Moderator access to Twitter account

Tags: feature-request, promotion, chat, twitter

Over on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/389/user-experience), we're talking about [picking a day and topic](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/436/waking-up-chat-with-weekly-chat-sessions), and scheduling "grand opening" event to get a bunch of people in the room at one time.

In order to get the word out to as many as many people as possible, I'd like to send out a note on Twitter. Can we get access to the [@StackUX](http://twitter.com/StackUX) account for posting announcements like these?

Comment: Related: [Would allowing moderators to update their stacks' twitter accounts improve visibility and offer more value?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92235/would-allowing-moderators-to-update-their-stacks-twitter-accounts-improve-visibi)

Comment: @Rahul Thanks. I knew this had been brought up before. Couldn't find your MSO post.